# python: add another point in the triangle/corner plot

Tags: python, plot

I am using the triangle/corner plot from python and I follow the simple guide in [this webpage](http://eso-python.github.io/ESOPythonTutorials/ESOPythonDemoDay8_MCMC_with_emcee.html). Everything is ok but I was thinking about adding another point in the triangle plot. As you can see from the example, the command to draw the triangle plot with a particular point is:

```
fig = triangle.corner(samples, labels=["$m$", "$b$"],truths=[m_true, b_true])
```

in which `m_true` and `b_true` are the coordinates of the blue square. How can I add another point with different coordinates, let's say `{b_true2, m_true2}`?

Comment: It would help if you mentioned that you were using [`triangle_plot`](https://github.com/dfm/corner.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit over the `ax`. So if you want to plot something above, you have to do:

1. `figure, ax = pl.subplots(1, 1)`
2. `figure = triangle.corner(samples, labels=["$m$", "$b$"],truths=[m_true, b_true])`
3. `ax.plot(...)`

Comment: I could not understand the answer.