# Corner plot add another point

Tags: python, plot, contour, mcmc

I am using the following MWE:

```
def contour(fit, mu_des,dt_des):
    la = fit.extract(permuted=True)
    mu_pos = np.vstack((la['mu'])).T
    dt_pos = np.vstack((la['dt'])).T
    postsamples = np.vstack((mu_pos, dt_pos)).T
    fig = corner.corner(postsamples, labels=[r"$\mu$", r"$dt$"],color='g', smooth=1,
                        levels=(0.68,0.95),plot_density=0, fill_contours=1, plot_datapoints=1,
                           truths=list([mu_des,dt_des]))
    return fig
```

Now I also want to show a custom point in the plot. The question is somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209237/python-add-another-point-in-the-triangle-corner-plot), but I could not follow the answer. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got my answer following the [link given below.](https://corner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom.html)
One can change the function as

```
def contour(fit):
    la = fit.extract(permuted=True)
    mu_pos = np.vstack((la['mu'])).T
    dt_pos = np.vstack((la['dt'])).T
    #print(mu_pos.shape)
    #P_pos=np.vstack((la['P'])).T
    postsamples = np.vstack((mu_pos, dt_pos)).T
    #print(postsamples.shape)
    fig = corner.corner(postsamples, labels=[r"$\mu$", r"$dt$"],color='g', smooth=1,
                        levels=(0.68,0.95),plot_density=0, fill_contours=1, plot_datapoints=1,
                           truths=list([mu_des,dt_des]))
    axes = np.array(fig.axes).reshape((2, 2)); print(axes)
    ax = axes[1, 0]; 
    ax.plot(value1, value2, "sg")
    return fig
```